# Probability Mass function and Cumulative distribution function of Z

Tags: probability

An (incomplete) card deck contains 36 cards, of ranks 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 (of all
four suits). Two cards are picked at random without replacement. Let Z denote the random variable which
is the maximal rank of the two cards picked (for example, if 6, 7 are picked then Z = 7).

Compute the
probability mass function and the cumulative distribution function of Z.

PMF = P(X=x)= ????

What is the expected value (i.e.
math. expectation) of Z?

I have been reading about the concept of probability mass functions for 20 minutes and I cannot really understand how it is applied to this problem... I understand that it deals with discrete random variables which is obviously relevant to this problem.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.. please consider using either MathJax or LaTeX to format the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are $\binom{36}{2}$ ways to choose two cards.

$6$ will give $Z=2$

$6+4\cdot4=22$ will give $Z=3$

$6+4\cdot8=38$ will give $Z=4$

...

$6+4\cdot32=134$ will give $Z=10$

Therefore the answer is $Z=\frac{6*2+22*3+...+134*10}{\binom{36}2}=\frac{158}{21}$, or $7.523809$...

Comment: So we can write the probability mass function as a function of $z$ as $f_Z(z)=\Pr(Z=z)=\frac{6+16(z-2)}{\binom{36}{2}}$ for $z\in\{2,\dots,10\}$.